# MongoDB shell: update properties with regex changing existing property

Tags: mongodb

I need to chage this:

```
userId: 'sdfsd'
pictures: ['https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask.jpg', 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask2.jpg']
```

To this:

```
userId: 'sdfsd'
pictures: ['ask.jpg', 'ask2.jpg']
```

Is there way to do it with just one command?

Comment: MongoDB version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need apply regex for your use case.

### MongoDb way (v4.2)

We split by `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/` or `/` and take last item.

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
    $set: {
      pictures: {
        $map: {
          input: "$pictures",
          in: {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $split: [
                  "$$this",
                  "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/" // or split by "/"
                ]
              },
              -1
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

### JS way

We can apply regex, split, etc... and save individually.

```
db.collection.find({}).forEach(function(doc){
   doc.pictures = doc.pictures.map(x => x.replace("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/", ""));
   db.collection.save(doc);
})
```